# Android file storage (documents path)

Tags: android, android-camera, android-file

**Background:**
I'm doing some researches about file storage and tried to save data in an example application. It didn't work and the error "Access denied" were thrown (working with an emulator with API 29).

I read about the storage permissions being changed with API 29. According to this [article](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#java), the user can select a path by using the file chooser and grant access for the app, to operate in. The access is given, until the device restarts. I need rather something, where the application can have access for eternity, since to ask the user to choose a path every time after restart, could be annoying.

**Goal:**
My main goal is to have a folder, that both user and the application has access to. The app should create a pdf file (using android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument) based on users entries and give the user the ability to take 1-2 photos using the Camera.

If the user presses the finish button in the application, the app should create a subfolder in the shared folder and put the created pdf file and the pictures in it.

**TL;DR:**
How am I able to operate (creating / reading files and folders) in a folder, which is accessible for both the application and user (API 29).

Comment: With Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE you can let the user select any directory. Needed only once.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by a folder accessible by a user. Or with by both user and application.

Comment: `and grant access for the app, to operate in. The access is given, until the device restarts. ` The user or your app cannot grand anyting. Instead your app can take permissions granted by providers. And they are persistend under device reboots.

Comment: Take persistable permissions. See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#persist-permissions and https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/27/scoped-storage-stories-durable-access.html.

Comment: @blackapps according to the developer pages of android, there are some encapsulated internal space for apps with API 29 that is hidden for the user and only accessible for the app: _"Internal storage has the added benefit of the data being hidden from users."_

Comment: It is time you come with conclusions.